# How to turn an MSSQL database to SQLite database for Android

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have an MSSQL database. I want to use it in an Android app. I apparently need to turn it to an SQLite database. How I can do that? All I can do in SQL is getting a .bak file which seems useless for my purpose so far. Can you tell me how I should get the database from Microsoft SQL Management Console and how I should add to my Android project? Thanks.

Comment: You could... **1** use the MySQL db through a webservice. OR **2** Export your MySQL db to a common format (probably, a serie of CSV files - 1 per table), then re-import it into SQLite (you'll have to remake the indexes, the keys, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [DBConvert](https://dbconvert.com/sqlite/mssql/)

https://dbconvert.com/sqlite/mssql/

**DBConvert for SQLite & MSSQL**

```
SQLite → MS SQL Server, MS SQL Dump
SQL Server → SQLite, MS SQL Dump
SQLite ↔ SQL Azure
SQLite ↔ Amazon RDS
```

**DBSync for SQLite & MSSQL**

```
SQLite ↔ Microsoft SQL Server
SQLite ↔ SQL Azure
SQLite ↔ Amazon RDS
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you also tell me how to extract the database from SQL using Management Console?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dB  using dbmigration to any type you want
You just need select the source database and destination type you want then Good to Go
Follow the below link to download
https://download.cnet.com/dbMigration-NET/3000-10254_4-76452016.html